# What is the difference in meaning between credit and accredit?

Tags: word-usage

> 'his account had been credited with $500' OR 
>   'his account had been accredited with $500
>
> Which of these is correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect users to provide some [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like any research you have done to answer your own question. In particular, what did the dictionary say? Is there something specific that you did not understand after consulting the dictionary?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246671/the-difference-between-credit-and-accredit

Answer (score 1):

*To credit* means to add something to an account, or to say that someone participated in completing a project or job.

*To accredit* can be used to say that someone participated in completing a project or job, but is usually meant in a "higher-level" sense.  For example, we might accreddit a leader with moving a company in a certain direction, but you wouldn't accreddit someone for a job well done.

*Accredit* is more often used to say that an institution has the ability to give recognized credentials, such as a school.

*Accredit* never means to add something to an account.